# Why is property 'then' undefined in Codecademy React project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is a React project that interacts with Spotify API. Everything seems to be working until my search function in Spotify.js returns an array with the track information, which is chained to setState in App.js but I get an error: ×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Sorry if too much or not enough info... Completely new to coding and appreciate anyone who can help me understand what's going wrong. Thank you!

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import SearchBar from '../SearchBar/SearchBar';
import SearchResults from '../SearchResults/SearchResults';
import Playlist from '../Playlist/Playlist';
import Spotify from '../../Util/Spotify';

import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchResults: [],
      playlistName: 'playlist1',
      playlistTracks: []
    };
    this.addTrack = this.addTrack.bind(this);
    this.removeTrack = this.removeTrack.bind(this);
    this.updatePlaylistName = this.updatePlaylistName.bind(this);
    this.savePlaylist = this.savePlaylist.bind(this);
    this.search = this.search.bind(this);
  }

  addTrack(track) {
    let tracks = this.state.playlistTracks;
    if (tracks.find(savedTrack => savedTrack.id === track.id)) {
      return;
    } else {
      tracks.push(track);
    }
    this.setState({playlistTracks: tracks});
  }

  removeTrack(track) {
    let tracks = this.state.playlistTracks;
    tracks = tracks.filter(currentTrack => currentTrack.id !== track.id);
    this.setState({ playlistTracks: tracks });
  }

  updatePlaylistName(name) {
    this.setState({ playlistName: name })
  }

  savePlaylist() {
    const trackUris = this.state.playlistTracks.map(track => track.uri);
    Spotify.savePlaylist(this.state.playlistName, trackUris).then(() => {
      this.setState({
        playlistName: 'New Playlist',
        playlistTracks: []
      })
    })
  }

  search(term) {
    Spotify.search(term).then(searchResults => {
      this.setState({ searchResults: searchResults })
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Ja<span className="highlight">mmm</span>ing</h1>
        <div className="App">
          <SearchBar onSearch={this.search} />
          <div className="App-playlist">
            <SearchResults searchResults={this.state.searchResults} 
            onAdd={this.addTrack} />
            <Playlist playlistName={this.state.playlistName} 
            playlistTracks={this.state.playlistTracks} 
            onRemove={this.removeTrack} 
            onNameChange={this.updatePlaylistName}
            onSave={this.savePlaylist} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

App.js passes search to SearchBar.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './SearchBar.css';

class SearchBar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            term: ''
        }
        this.search = this.search.bind(this);
        this.handleTermChange = this.handleTermChange.bind(this);
    }

    search() {
        this.props.onSearch(this.state.term);
    }

    handleTermChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            term: event.target.value
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="SearchBar">
            <input placeholder="Enter A Song, Album, or Artist" 
            onChange={this.handleTermChange} />
            <button onClick={this.search} className="SearchButton">SEARCH</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default SearchBar;
```

SearchBar.js passes term back to App.js, calls search in Spotify.js:

```
let accessToken;
const clientID = 'clientID';
const redirectURI = "http://localhost:3000/";

const Spotify = {
    
    search(term) {
        const accessToken = Spotify.getAccessToken();
        fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?type=track&q=${term}`,
            { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` } 
        }).then(response => {
            return response.json();
        }).then(jsonResponse => {
            if (!jsonResponse.tracks) {
                return [];
            }
            return jsonResponse.tracks.items.map(track => ({
                    id: track.id,
                    name: track.name,
                    artist: track.artists[0].name,
                    album: track.album.name,
                    uri: track.uri
            }));
        });
    },

    savePlaylist(name, trackUris) {
        if (!name || !trackUris.length) {
            return;
        };
        let accessToken = Spotify.getAccessToken();
        let headers = {Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`};
        let userID;
        return fetch('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me', {headers: headers}
        ).then(response => {
            response.json();
        }).then(jsonResponse => {
            userID = jsonResponse.id;
            return fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/user/${userID}/playlists`,
            {
                headers: headers,
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({name: name})
            }).then(response => response.json()
            ).then(jsonResponse => {
                const playlistID = jsonResponse.id;
                return fetch(`/v1/users/${userID}/playlists/${playlistID}/tracks`,
                {
                    headers: headers,
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: JSON.stringify({uris: trackUris})
                })
            })
        })
    },

    getAccessToken() {
        if (accessToken) {
            return accessToken;
        }

        const accessTokenMatch = window.location.href.match(/access_token=([^&]*)/);
        const expiresInMatch = window.location.href.match(/expires_in=([^&]*)/);

        if (accessTokenMatch && expiresInMatch) {
            accessToken = accessTokenMatch[1];
            const expiresIn = Number(expiresInMatch[1]);
            window.setTimeout(() => accessToken = '', expiresIn * 1000);
            window.history.pushState('Access Token', null, '/');
            return accessToken;
        } else {
            const accessURL = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=${clientID}&response_type=token&scope=playlist-modify-public&redirect_uri=${redirectURI}`;
            window.location = accessURL;
        }
    }
};

export default Spotify;
```

Spotify.search returns an array, but App.search says: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Comment: `search()` doe not return an array. It returns undefined. The callback to `then()` returns an array. Try putting `return` in front of `fetch()`

Comment: *"Spotify.search returns an array"* No, it doesn't. It doesn't return anything at all (and so calling it results in `undefined`). You need to add `return` in front of `fetch` so you return the promise chain, which will have a `then` method `API.search` can use.

Comment: Strange that you used `return fetch()` in `savePlaylist()` correctly but not in `search()`

Comment: Not sure if folks say it here but, THANK YOU ALL SO MUCH! @charlietfl it's because I was trying to fix things all over the place and must have encountered the correct usage somewhere, but failed to apply it consistently. Just not seeing things that quickly yet.

Comment: Understand. Learning curve can seem overwhelming sometimes